# AngularJS ng-options setting default select value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
app.factory("ParentsFactory", function ($http) {
```

```
    return $http.get("/home/parents");
})

ParentsFactory.then(function (data) {
    $scope.Parents = data.data;
});
```

`<select class="form-control" ng-model="modelparent">
                                <option value="{{parent.ParentID}}" ng-selected="{{parent.ParentID==2}}" ng-repeat="parent in Parents">{{parent.DocumentNo}} -  {{parent.FullName}}</option>
                            </select>`

Comment: Sorry, but what is your concrete question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove interpolation braces {{}} from ng-selected and try:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="modelparent">
                            <option value="{{parent.ParentID}}" ng-repeat="parent in Parents"  ng-selected="parent.ParentID==2">{{parent.DocumentNo}} -  {{parent.FullName}}</option>
                        </select>
```

**Edit:**

According to your data i have edited my answer:

```js
var app=angular.module("app",[]);
 app.controller('Ctrl',['$scope',Ctrl]);
 
function Ctrl($scope){
$scope.modelparent = "1";
    $scope.Parents = [{ "ParentID": 1, "FullName": "Jack", "BirthDate": "/Date(631137600000)/", "BirthPalace": 1, "DocumentType": 1, "DocumentNo": "P544123", "AddDate": "/Date(1483300800000)/", "UpdateDate": null, "LastLoginDate": null }, 
    { "ParentID": 2, "FullName": "Ammanda", "BirthDate": "/Date(631137600000)/", "BirthPalace": 1, "DocumentType": 1, "DocumentNo": "P5441234", "AddDate": "/Date(1483300800000)/", "UpdateDate": null, "LastLoginDate": null }]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-app="app">
{{Abc}}
<select class="form-control" ng-model="modelparent">
                                <option value="{{parent.ParentID}}" ng-repeat="parent in Parents">{{parent.DocumentNo}} {{parent.FullName}}</option>
                            </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @user3186875 please give Parents data

Comment: where is data ?

Comment: Parents will be object right? please postthat json or what ever you have in parents here

Comment: [{ "ParentID": 1, "FullName": "Jack", "BirthDate": "/Date(631137600000)/", "BirthPalace": 1, "DocumentType": 1, "DocumentNo": "P544123", "AddDate": "/Date(1483300800000)/", "UpdateDate": null, "LastLoginDate": null }, { "ParentID": 2, "FullName": "Ammanda", "BirthDate": "/Date(631137600000)/", "BirthPalace": 1, "DocumentType": 1, "DocumentNo": "P5441234", "AddDate": "/Date(1483300800000)/", "UpdateDate": null, "LastLoginDate": null }]

Comment: @jvdnet see my edits you can assign value to model no need to give ng selected

Comment: @jvdnet happy to help you